# Match 2 lines in file

Tags: python, xml

I have a XML file I am trying to read which contains multiple lines however there are 2 lines I'm particularly searching for.

```
<intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I want to search for `android:scheme` but only if it has the 'BROWSABLE' category before or after it. If this matches, print them out.

If `android:scheme` is on its own, and doesn't have the 'BROWSABLE' attribute, ignore it.

Comment: XML is usually not a good use case for regular expressions, especially if there can be nested items. The various different ways of where spaces may be inserted would also bloat it up notably. Better use a true XML parser.

Comment: ah ok, thanks, I'm looking into some XML parsers

Comment: Can you share the file?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) in the following manner (use `pip install xmltodict` first to install it):

I used this xml file (named 'xml_stack_overflow_question.xml' in the code):

```
<doc>
<intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.NOTBROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="myapp2"/>
</intent-filter>
</doc>
```

and this code:

```
import xmltodict

with open('xml_stack_overflow_question.xml') as f:
    doc_file = xmltodict.parse(f.read())

for filter in (doc_file['doc']['intent-filter']):
    if filter['category']['@android:name'] == "android.intent.category.BROWSABLE":
        print "Match Found: " + filter['data']['@android:scheme']
```

The output would be:

```
Match Found: myapp
```

Which means only the entry with the "BROWSABLE" category got fetched (as opposed to the second one which is "**NOT**BROWSABLE"

Comment: If in the second case, of **NOT**BROWSABLE, there would be no tag at all for the category, you can simply check for its existence (the `doc_file` is an `OrderedDict`)